# python web based game

Tags: python, web, client-side, server-side

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a web based game in python. I have searched the internet and cannot seem to find any tutorial or document pointing to this. Any advice will be appreciated..

Comment: The clarification you gave in the comments below you should mention up here in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the only ways I know to "directly" code in python for the web :

- [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) which is a python to pyjamas compiler. See this [asteroid example](http://pyjs.org/examples/asteroids/output/Space.html) (buggy on Chrome). I made one myself and simple stuffs are working well but you can't display text on the canvas at the moment. And i guess It would be much slower than pure javascript.
- [IronPython with Silverlight](http://ironpython.net/browser/) and [here a tutorial](http://www.learningpython.com/2007/07/29/creating-a-game-using-python-and-silverlight-11/).
- [Panda3D and its plugin](http://www.panda3d.org/download.php?runtime), so you'll have to ask the players to download that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague but from what I understand you are trying to create a web based game with Python.

As python is a serverside language you could implement the website/server with it but for the client and the game itself you will need a browser based client-side technology. Like [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash), [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/), [WEBGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) or Even Javascript and [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5). But this will all depend on how you would like to structure your game.

You could create a Server that pushes information to the clients with a library with say [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). The other option you could choose is to create a website that the clients will poll for information or use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) for Push.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. But without more information on what *type* of game it is impossible to provide further guidance.

Comment: I have implemented a simple tetris game in python using pygame and am wondering if there is anyway I could run it in a browser.I dont mind having to use anyother tool other than pygame

Comment: Stuff that runs on the client side needs to be in a client-side language. http://pyjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Python is a serverside language. For the "web" in web-based you still need HTML und JS (or Flash). Using Python for the serverside is possible. [Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) is a list of Python web frameworks (my personal favorite is Django).

Answer (score 0):

Python can be used in a variety of ways for developing web games. In particular, it can be very useful for doing the back-end of a multiplayer game. For the front-end you will probably need to use a client-side technology like Flash, but there have been turn-based games that simply use static HTML as the front-end (for example, Urban Dead) and that could be implemented in Python alone without a separate client-side technology.